# How to get information about currently deployed process to show custom process diagram in Activiti

Tags: activiti, bpmn

We are using Activiti to model processes in our spring-mvc environment.

I would like to generate a custom overview of the entire process including the current position of the process.

Activiti provides the possibility to generate a png by using

```
ProcessDiagramGenerator.generatePngDiagram
```

See the [documentation](http://activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/impl/bpmn/diagram/ProcessDiagramGenerator.html#generatePngDiagram%28org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ProcessDefinitionEntity%29)

However I would like to create a custom rendering of the process in an html page. For this I need information about the process.

What makes this so difficult is that I only want to show user tasks of a specific user and do this for multiple processes. Some are missing a few steps.

I know how to get the currently active tasks, but I am more interested in all the possible tasks a user will encounter in the process.

Does anyone know how to get e.g. a list of all the user tasks of a specific user for a process deployed to the engine?

Answer (score 2):

if you want a list of tasks the user is a candidate for you can use:

```
List<Task> userCandidateTasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskCandidateUser(username).list();
```

or for tasks assigned to this user:

```
List<Task> userAssignedTasks = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskAssignee(username).list();
```

then if you want these to appear on the diagram, you can get the IDs of the tasks you want (for instance you could merge both the tasks the user is a candidate and assignee) and then you just pass the list of IDs to the method:

```
InputStream imageStream = ProcessDiagramGenerator.generateDiagram(processDefinition, "png", tasksIdList);
```